# Replace Newline With Space In Array Element In a For Loop In Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I'm assigning values to an array inside a for loop:

```
aws_user_roles+=("$aws_role_name")
```

If I were assigning the values of the array from a command and want to strip the newline I could go:

```
 readarray -t aws_roles < <(...some aws commands...)
```

My for loop looks something like this:

```
for ((has_role_index=0;has_role_index<${#aws_user_has_roles[@]};++has_role_index)); do         
             aws_user_roles+=("$aws_role_name")
             declare -p aws_user_roles
done
```

How can I strip out the newline from the array elements in `aws_user_roles` and replace it with a space?

Comment: Do you really want to replace newlines with spaces, or do you want each line to be a separate array element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern substitution:

```
aws_user_roles+=("${aws_role_name//$'\n'/ }")
```

From `man bash`:

> **${parameter/pattern/string}**
>
> Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced

Answer (score 3):

Use `tr`:

```
aws_user_roles+=("$(<<<"$aws_role_name" tr '\n' ' ')")
```

- `$(..)` is command substitution
- `<<<"$variable"` is a here-string
- `tr '\n' ' '` substitutes newlines for spaces.